# usb_modeswitch is hangs on manual switch

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

I have 3.2.27 Linux kernel with `Busybox`. I am using `Raspberry PI`. When I pluging my Huawei E303c dmesg showing

```
[    4.569781] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    4.681078] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14fe
[    4.690885] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    4.701143] usb 1-1.2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[    4.708326] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[    4.718185] scsi0 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[    4.726518] scsi1 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.1
[    5.720951] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[    5.738561] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   SD Storage       2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[    5.755514] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

The option kernel module is already running but usb-storage module not running. But when I enter usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x14fe -H it's hangs like

```
Looking for default devices ...
 Found default devices (1)
Accessing device 002 on bus 002 ...
Using endpoints 0x04 (out) and 0x83 (in)
Inquiring device details; driver will be detached ...
Looking for active driver ...
 OK, driver found ("usb-storage")
 OK, driver "usb-storage" detached
```

Can anyone give me a solution,

Comment: Do you actually need to ever use the usb-storage driver with this device?  If not you can set it to ignore this device with the quirks flag.  You might also see if there's an automatic filesystem mount through that driver which you need to get rid of first.

Comment: I don't need usb-storage kernel module and I don't have this module installed. Can you give me an example to use quirks flag. Thanks

Comment: You may not need it, but you do have the module installed, and it's being loaded by something, perhaps udev, in which case you can write a udev rule for it.  You'll have to look up the quirks documentation, but the key point is that you'll need to change where the module is being loaded to add the quirks line, add it to the module loader configuration, or else unload it and reload with the quirks.  It's particularly annoying if it's being loaded in the initrd image early in boot, since that's a more involved process to change.

Comment: thanks.. Let me try and I will get back to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has solve my issue

```
usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf -W -I

modprobe option
modprobe ppp_generic
```

My /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf looks like

```
# Huawei E303c
DefaultVendor= 0x12d1
DefaultProduct=0x14fe

TargetVendor=  0x12d1
TargetProductList="1001,1406,140b,140c,1412,141b,14ac,1506"

CheckSuccess=20

MessageEndpoint= 0x01
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```